# uitableview issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a navigation based application , start with uitableview , I want when return to the uitableview be refreshed

I mean how when return from screen back to this uitablview

anu suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I tired it but it give bad_exec , I have function that fill nsaarry and it be used to populate the uitableview. I tried -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; [self loaddata];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: You have to replace `self.tableView` with whatever you named your `UITableView`.